# shell script to make "update" sql commands from the list of variables stored in a text file

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have a textfile "users.txt" which contains variables like below:

```
trialuser1,paidUser1,paidPasswd1,paidDate1
trialuser2,paidUser2,paidPasswd2,paidDate2
trialuser3,paidUser3,paidPasswd3,paidDate3
trialuser4,paidUser4,paidPasswd4,paidDate4
trialuser5,paidUser5,paidPasswd5,paidDate5
....
....
....
```

Now, I want to make a shell script which will create a sql "updateusers.sql" file which contains "Update" sql statements using the variables stored in the above textfile as :

```
update systemx.thetable set username='paidUser1',password='paidPasswd1',payment='paid',paidDate='paidDate1',token='init' where username='trialuser1'; 
update systemx.thetable set username='paidUser2',password='paidPasswd2',payment='paid',paidDate='paidDate2',token='init' where username='trialuser2'; 
update systemx.thetable set username='paidUser3',password='paidPasswd3',payment='paid',paidDate='paidDate3',token='init' where username='trialuser3'; 
update systemx.thetable set username='paidUser4',password='paidPasswd4',payment='paid',paidDate='paidDate4',token='init' where username='trialuser4'; 
update systemx.thetable set username='paidUser5',password='paidPasswd5',payment='paid',paidDate='paidDate5',token='init' where username='trialuser5'; 
....
....
....
```

Comment: do you want the output lines to contain the literal string `'2017-08-17'` as in your example output, or do you want it to contain the fourth field of each input line (`paidDateN` )?

Comment: @cas -actually for the date part I want the sql to contain the fourth field of each input line.

Comment: ok, I updated my awk script.   not using $4 seemed odd to me (which is why i asked) but my original version followed your sample output rather than make an assumption.

Comment: thank you @cas .. I think I should change my sample output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { 
    FS=",";
    fmt="update systemx.thetable set username='%s'," \
        "password='%s',payment='paid',paidDate='%s'," \
        "token='init' where username='%s';\n";
};

{ printf fmt, $2, $3, $4, $1 };
```

save as, e.g., `samin.awk`, make executable with `chmod +x samin.awk`, then:

```
$ ./samin.awk users.txt
update systemx.thetable set username='paidUser1',password='paidPasswd1',payment='paid',paidDate='paidDate1',token='init' where username='trialuser1';
update systemx.thetable set username='paidUser2',password='paidPasswd2',payment='paid',paidDate='paidDate2',token='init' where username='trialuser2';
update systemx.thetable set username='paidUser3',password='paidPasswd3',payment='paid',paidDate='paidDate3',token='init' where username='trialuser3';
update systemx.thetable set username='paidUser4',password='paidPasswd4',payment='paid',paidDate='paidDate4',token='init' where username='trialuser4';
update systemx.thetable set username='paidUser5',password='paidPasswd5',payment='paid',paidDate='paidDate5',token='init' where username='trialuser5';
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is indeed a good choice for processing files a line at a time and transforming them somehow; here's how I came up with it:

```
awk -F, '{print "update systemx.thetable set username='\''"$2"'\'',password='\''"$3"'\'',payment='\''paid'\'',paidDate='\''"$4"'\'',token='\''init'\'' where username='\''"$1"'\'';"}' users.txt
```

where I assumed you wanted the field 4, "paidDate5", instead of the static date "2017-08-17".

This will print the corresponding text to the screen; you could redirect it to a sql script for later execution.

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F, '{ printf("update systemx.thetable set username=\047%s\047,password=\047%s\047,
           payment=\047paid\047,paidDate=\047%s\047,token=\047init\047 
           where username=\047%s\047;\n",$2,$3,$4,$1) }' file
```

The output:

```
update systemx.thetable set username='paidUser1',password='paidPasswd1',payment='paid',paidDate='paidDate1',token='init' where username='trialuser1';
update systemx.thetable set username='paidUser2',password='paidPasswd2',payment='paid',paidDate='paidDate2',token='init' where username='trialuser2';
update systemx.thetable set username='paidUser3',password='paidPasswd3',payment='paid',paidDate='paidDate3',token='init' where username='trialuser3';
update systemx.thetable set username='paidUser4',password='paidPasswd4',payment='paid',paidDate='paidDate4',token='init' where username='trialuser4';
update systemx.thetable set username='paidUser5',password='paidPasswd5',payment='paid',paidDate='paidDate5',token='init' where username='trialuser5';
```

Comment: thank you for the solution @RomanPerekhrest .. could you please let me know what "\047" is? It is being used to print single inverted comma right?but could you please clarify a bit.